# Determinant of an $n×n$ identity matrix with two arbitrary rows

Tags: matrices, determinant

It seems true that the determinant should be the two rows with numbers and take from it only two columns where there aren't 1s in their columns. But I can't prove it's true.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Can you please phrase it differently?

Comment: You have the I matrix .  Now you fill / change two rows to numbers.   What will be the determination?   I claim it should be a 2×2 determination of the two rows × two coloms which have only zeroes in them. But how to prove it?

Comment: Yes I mean determinant. Sorry for tha

Answer (score 0):

Computing directly that determinant, if the entries as $a_{ij}$ where for $j>2$, then calling the matrix $A$ and the determinant of the attached matrices:
$$|A|= a_{11}\cdot A_{11} + a_{12}\cdot A_{12}$$
Being the first two rows the rows that are changed. We now have that $A_{11}=a_{22}$ and $A_{12}=a_{21}$. So finally the determinant of that matrix is the cross multiplication or that four elements:
$$|A| = a_{11}\cdot a_{22}+ a_{12}\cdot a_{21}$$